# Cakephp combine columns with the same name or group

Tags: sql, cakephp, merge, cakephp-2.0

I'm using CakePHP as a framework for my project. In here, I have a Group and Name columns. I've been trying my best to combine the data with the same group.

My code in the controller is this:

```
> $this->Custom->Rental->find('all', array('Pool' => 'name'));
> $this->set('rents', $this->Paginator->paginate('Rental'));
```

This is my current table..

```
Group                          Name
1                              A
2                              D
1                              W
3                              C
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
Group                          Name
1                              A
                               W
2                              D
3                              C
```

It will just show one group number if they have the same number. I'm sorry for the noob question. I was working on it for 2 days already and I can't find the solution.

Comment: Simply use SQLs `group by` if I get that question right?

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea:

**controller**

```
$this->Paginator->order = 'Rental.group_id ASC';
$this->set('rents', $this->Paginator->paginate('Rental'));
```

**view**

```
<?php
 $group = '';
 foreach ($rents AS $rent) { 
   if($group != $rent['Rental']['group_id']) {
      echo $rent['Rental']['group_id'];
   }  
   echo $rent['Rental']['name'];
   $group = $rent['Rental']['group_id']; 
 } ?>
```